# How do I reduce the time shiny spends on .rs.setShinyBreakpoints as documented in profvis()?

Tags: r, shiny, profvis

My very large app has a long delay at startup. I am trying to track down and fix whatever is causing the delay.

In the course of this I am learning to use profvis(). In going through the flame plot there are two huge delays (3480ms and 3540ms) before it even gets to my code. The stack is:

`.rs.setShinyBreakpoints / .rs.setFunctionBreakpoints / .rs.tracedSourceRefs`

with some isTrue scattered about the stacks.

I can't find anything on what these blocks do, but if they are there to notice breakpoints, is there a way to disable this if I am not debugging? Or is there something else wrong?

Here is a link to the Rprof file if it is of help.
[Profile File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n9AwBofuxU4N-Bdkr-Jv2FnvDkBbjKBA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: How are you running your app? Those `.rs.*` functions are RStudio functions that aren't really part of your app and are just part of the IDE. I'm guessing you wouldn't see those if you run and profile your app using the standard R GUI.

Comment: I have the app loaded in RStudio then click the Run App button.